# Scalability in Scala

Tags: scala, scalability

I am going through Scala book by Martin Odersky.

It states that Scala language is highly scalable,reason being that it allows users to add new features which can be utilised as native language support.

It has got me confused with the term 'Scalability'.

I understand that scalability means ability of a software to handle huge amount of data.

So what's the difference here?

Comment: You can apply the word "Scalability" to a variety of topics, not just throughput.

Comment: ...so in context of Scala scalability means ability to add more features more easily, and it has nothing to do with throughput.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of Scala, Odersky usually means that it is *scalable* in the sense that it can be used for a wide range of tasks, from simple scripting to large libraries to behemoth enterprise applications.

It's good for scripting because of its type inference, relatively low verbosity (compared to Java), and functional style (which generally lends itself to more concise code).

It's good for medium size applications and libraries because of its powerful type system, which means it is possible to write code that mostly or only produces errors at compile time rather than runtime (to the extent that is possible). The Play! framework in particular is founded on this philosophy. Furthermore, Scala runs on the JVM and therefore can harness any of the many, many Java libraries out there.

And it's good for enterprise software because it compiles to JVM bytecode, which already has a great track record in enterprise software; further, the fact that it's statically typed makes the maintenance of very large codebases much easier.

Scala is also applicable to a number of other areas, making it even more "scalable": concurrency/parallelism and domain-specific languages come to mind.

[Here is a presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/rawwell/scalaliftoff2009pdf) by Odersky, if you start at slide 6 and go forward, you'll see him explain some other uses of Scala as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a detailed reply.

Comment: It's also scalable in the sense that you can add what looks like new syntax in library code that in other languages would have to be built into the language itself.

Comment: @Jasper-M isn't that what's meant by a domain specific language?

Comment: It's what enables the creation of expressive DSLs.